# How to convert Newick tree format to TikZ?

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I need to draw a number of large phylogenetic tree diagrams in a document and it appears that tikz-qtree may be the best package for this task. A manual approach does not seem the best solution to converting the trees from the Newick tree format generated by phylogenetic software to TikZ code. It would be arduous and error prone to do the conversion manually and I'm hoping that someone has developed an automated conversion. Does anyone here know of such a solution?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input you want to use? You don't want to tell people to search for this Newick format thingy. :)

Comment: Also please provide a picture of the tree as it is rendered in the Newick software. It might aid in unerstanding the format.

Comment: Seems to be this format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format

Comment: Alex correctly identified an appropriate reference for the Newick tree format at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format. Also, Newick is not software, but rather a text-based format for representing binary trees. It is fairly standard in the biological sciences. Many non-standardized extensions exist, but I'm only concerned with basic and standard implementation here.

Comment: As it stands, this seems to require an entire package writing, which makes it too broad. Could you show us what code you've already got written?